# How can I convert a correlation or similarity table to 696x696 matrix

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, distance, correlation, similarity

So here is the full dataset in pastebin: `https://pastebin.com/xpGMsSSf`

Quick snap of the pastebin:

```
`"V1","V2","N"
16,17,0.065532029
16,30,0.070163826
17,30,0.053089888
29,30,0.068024596`
```

**Pre-processing of the data:** I started with a list of customer orders and items within each order. I calculated number of occurrences of each pair of items within the same order. Then, I used the "Jackkard Index" to calculate similarities between the items. Now I am where you can see in the dataset.

**The dataset:** The dataset contains the material numbers in V1 and V2. N = similarity index between the items. The dataset only contains the pair of items that occurred together in the same order. Therefore, the are a lot of pairs that are not in the dataset.

**My objective:** I have 696 unique item numbers ranging from 1-696. I want a 696x696 matrix by N as values. The values for "missing pairs" in the dataset should be equal to zero = meaning that there is no similarity between the two items.

**What am I going to use this for?** I want to cluster the 696 items based on their number of occurrences within the same order.

Comment: after setting the variables `V1` and `V2` to factors (set the `levels` to what you want ie `1:696`), you can use `xtabs( N ~ V1 + V2, mat, sparse=TRUE`

Comment: Can you explain a little further? I'm a completely beginner. How can I set the levels to 1:696?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xtabs` can be used to get the data in the form you want - it also has the nice feature that you can specify the outcome as a sparse matrix (which yours is (`nrow(dat)/696^2`)

```
dat <- read.csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/xpGMsSSf")

# setting to factor introduces factor levels that are not found in the data
# see below for what is being done
dat[c("V1", "V2")] <- lapply(dat[c("V1", "V2")], factor, levels=1:696)

out <- xtabs( N ~ V1 + V2, dat, sparse=TRUE)

out[1:5, 1:5]

# To make symmetric
library(Matrix)
out[lower.tri(out)] <- t(out)[lower.tri(out)]
```

---

```
# Explanation of setting common factor levels
# example
x = c(1,2,3)
y = c(1,4,5)
table(x, y)
# but if we want both row and columns of table to include 1 to 5
# we can set to factor
x = factor(x, levels=1:5)
y = factor(y, levels=1:5)
table(x, y)
```

---

```
dput(head(mat))
structure(list(V1 = c(16L, 16L, 17L, 29L, 16L, 17L), V2 = c(17L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 29L, 29L), N = c(0.065532029, 0.070163826, 0.053089888, 
0.068024596, 0.053083392, 0.041870099)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", 
"N"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Unfortunately, it didn't help on the clustering though. So have to start over. I know this is a different question, but do you know how to perform this in R: http://www.dataanalytics.org.uk/Publications/S4E2e%20Support/exercises/Jaccard%20Dendrogram%20Excel.htm#calculation

Comment: Hi, @M.A ; sorry no. I don't really have experience on similarity / clustering. btw https://stats.stackexchange.com/ may be useful to get advice on such things - but be sure to fully explain your initial data and what you information you want to extract from it.